# Android list_item xml issue

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've go Android layout issue that crashed my mind. I have a FragmentActivity that hosts a Fragment. This fragment hasn't its own layout but populated with list items via custom ArrayAdapter. List items have xml layouts (ImageView and TextView). At the same time activity_layout serving as a fragment container has a specific background (rectangle gradient).

When application starts - all views rendered properly - list items background is transparent and i can see gradient from fragment container activity below items. But when i'm scrolling list gradient background is disappearing and i see a standard background from general theme. **How can i prevent it?**

I set ArrayAdapter in onCreate method of Fragment. OnCreateView is not overridden and returns null.

Comment: Do you use viewholder pattern?

Comment: Yeap... inner class ViewHolder in Adapter Class